# EXPLAIN DEPENDENCY in Apache spark

Tags: apache-spark, hive, sql-execution-plan

I am looking for a way to emulate Hive's `EXPLAIN DEPENDENCY SELECT ...` in Spark. The intention is to know what all inputs are necessary for current transformation/action.

I tried exact statement from Hive into SparkSQL but apparently Spark does not understand Hive's grammar entirely.

PS: This does not have to be SQL, DF API will also work.